# AmazonS3client ambiguous in the namespace 'Amazon.S3'

Tags: vb.net, amazon-s3

Can someone shed some light on this error:

> AmazonS3Client is ambiguous in the namespace 'Amazon.S3'

My code is:

```
Imports Amazon.s3
Public Sub New(ByVal sKey As String, ByVal sSecretKey As String)
    client = New Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client(sKey, sSecretKey)
End Sub
```

Comment: Just check whether the reference of `Amazon.s3` is pointing towards the correct path of the said `.dll`

Comment: I was able to figure it out. When referencing multiple Amazon dll's. You need to remove one of them from the references(even though it's not included in the name space) . This project was an upgrade from an older Amazon project..